# Compare two directories, but only a part of file name

Tags: diff

I have two directories with a lot of files. 
In one directory there are files eg

```
file_0001
file_0002
... etc,
```

and in the other directory files are

```
text_0001_file
text_0002_file
... etc.
```

`file_0001` and file `text_0001_file` are the same, one pair. I need to find a file without a pair. So I need to compare only a part of a name. How can I do that in bash?

Comment: you want to just check the file ? or compare the size... everything ?

Comment: Just compare file names in those directories.

Comment: Do you need to compare the subsequence part  of file names? like (0001) in file_0001 with (0001) in text_0001_file?

Comment: Yes, but they don't have to be numbers. One part of a file name is the same as one part of the other file. I just gave an example with a number. The same part of a name has more characters than 3 or more eg. fileAABBBB and 123BBBBwer.

Comment: Is it a fixed part of the file name in both directories? if yes which part is it?

Comment: No, it is not a fixed part. I found here something simmilar http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/178321/diff-two-directories-but-ignore-the-extensions. But how to adopt to my case

Comment: Content is the same in those similar name files so I could find similar names  and compare content? But how to find similar names, let say files which have 4 characters is a row the same in some position (eg at first 8 characters, 4 are the same or at last 6 characters 4 are the same)?

Comment: You're more likely to get a good answer if you give us some specifics of what you're actually trying to do.  The answer probably needs to find a reliable pattern in the naming convention which we cannot know with hypothetical examples.  Otherwise, if you want to figure it out yourself, you can try to use awk or sed to manipulate the file names for one list, and compare that to the other list.

Comment: Im am trying to compare two directories with thousands of files. Every file in dir1 has its twin in dir2 (eg. `IDwmkef1234.txt` and `aklsd1234skf.txt` are twins, they have `1234` part the same). There are a few files without a twin. I need those.

Comment: @HrvojeT do you know the column in which the text to compare occur for e.g dir1 in which all files like `IDwmkef1234.txt` having  common/filterable characters at 8-11 position  **or** dir2 in which all files like `aklsd1234skf` having common/filterable characters at 6-9 position?

Comment: One could give me an example with first 4 characters and I will adopt or a bash script could ask a user for input how many characters and how long would string be?

Comment: I found diff GUI called `meld`